# Video playing but not display in video js

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

I am using video js for playing video, I am adding src dynamically. first time video play fine. but second time only we can here audio only with black screen. when I refresh the page then first time video playing.please help me to solve this issue.

```
function playVideo() {
  var videoURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cEhbG3-2wY'
  videojs('player').ready(function() {
    this.on('play', function() {

    })
    this.src([
      { src: videoURL, type: "video/youtube" }
    ]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube ?

Answer (score -1):

To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method instead of `on()`.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. but still I m getting black screen with video audio. Is it need to reinitialize player instance because DOM is not creating.

Comment: Can you share your code through jsfiddle or similar service?